# Restkit core data detail data

Tags: core-data, restkit

I have to tables: Contract and ContractDetails which are connected with a relationship.

First I query for all Contracts using Restkit. Then a user taps on one Contract and forces a request to get the detail-data (ContractDetails).

the Contract-Details-JSON-response is something like this:

```
{
   "contractID" = "0815",
   "otherValues" = "doesn't matter here"
}
```

how do I setup a relationship between the two tables in my RestKit-configuration? RestKit should look up the Contract-Entry using the contractID and connect the detailsdata with the contractdata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the "Relationships" section of https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping.

Essentially, you create a mapping for both the Contract and ContractDetails and connect them via:

[detailsMapping mapKeyPath:@"contractID" toRelationship:@"contract" withMapping:contractMapping];